# 'Too many input argument' Error trying to run a script in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run a script given to me by my lecturer and I'm getting an error because of a function. The function is in a separate file but in the same directory. The function is an equation that will be double integrated in the main script.

Here is the main script(this file is titled 'ele_assignment_ii.m':

```
clear
format short

%The following part is for part (a)
dx = input('Enter the integration increment dx... \n >');
dy = input('Enter the integration increment dy... \n >');
total_charge=0;
for x=0:dx:1, 
for y=0:dy:1,
total_charge=rho_s_fun(x,y)*dx*dy+total_charge;
end
end
disp(sprintf('The total charge computed by manual double'));
disp(sprintf(' integration is %d nC',total_charge));
total_charge=dblquad(@rho_s_fun, 0, 1, 0, 1);
disp(sprintf('The total charge computed by the functional'))
disp(sprintf(' double integration is %d n',total_charge))

%The following for part (b)
Etotal=0;
for x=0:dx:1,
for y=0:dx:1,
rminusrprime=[-x -y 5];
numerator=rho_s_fun(x,y)*1e-9*dx*dy*rminusrprime;
denominator=4*pi*1e-9/(36*pi)*norm(rminusrprime)^3;
Etotal=Etotral+numerator/denominator;
end
end
disp(sprintf('The electric field computed by manual double'));
disp(sprintf(' integration is (%d, %d, %d) V/m',... 
    Etotal(1), Etotal(2), Etotal(1)))
```

Here is the function code (this file is titled rho_s_fun.m):

```
function rho_s_fun = rho_s_fun()
    rho_s_fun = @(x,y) (x.*y).*(x.^2 + y.^2 + 25).^(3/2);
end
```

And lastly, this is the error when I run the main script:

```
>> ele_assignment_ii
Enter the integration increment dx... 
 >2
Enter the integration increment dy... 
 >2
Error using rho_s_fun
Too many input arguments.

Error in ele_assignment_ii (line 10)
total_charge=rho_s_fun(x,y)*dx*dy+total_charge;
```

From my understanding, this error is apparently causing a subsequent error in line 10.

How can I change this code so it works?

Comment: Also you might be quick to point out "This is a common error and I should look into other questions and the solutions to them". Well all I can say is that A fly can fly but a bird cannot bird. I can't do what I don't know.

Comment: Try replacing the content of `rho_s_fun.m` with: `function z = rho_s_fun(x, y)` new line, `z = (x.*y).*(x.^2 + y.^2 + 25).^(3/2);` new line, `end`

Comment: You are mixing up anonymous functions and regular functions. In your file rho_s_fun.m  write the following two lines only:`function z = rho_s_fun(x,y)` and `z = (x.*y).*(x.^2 + y.^2 + 25).^(3/2);`

Comment: @Rotem in the function file yeah?

Comment: Yes, in the file “rho_s_fun.m”.

Comment: It seems to be working now but when I run the function file i get zero. Is that because I haven't defined x and y?